# Passing arrayCollection from flex to java

Tags: java, actionscript, blazeds

I am passing one ActionScript 3.0 arrayCollection containing multiple objects from Flex to Java side. Below is the arrayCollection:

```
  public var myAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {label:"A", data:"a"},
        {label:"B", data:"b"},
        {label:"C", data:"c"}
        ]);
```

I am using BlazeDS. I want to iterate over it and use that data in the java method. Please tell me what will be the data type of receiving parameter ? How to extract each object from that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [BlazeDS documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/index.html), an [`ArrayCollection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/io/ArrayCollection.html)... who would've thought? ;-)

As you can see, `ArrayCollection` is an `ArrayList` subclass -- this should mean you can treat it as such, too.